# Appending a menu to DOM on click with subsequent clicks creating only list item

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm building a Javascript menu builder which allows a user to items to a menu by filling inputs and then submit the data.

The idea is that on the first click the whole menu is placed in the DOM including the first list item. Subsequent clicks will only put an `<li>` element in the DOM.

Here is my code. The functions you should look at are createForm and createMenu:

[Codepen example](https://codepen.io/ryan_pixelers/pen/eBXXyP)

```
// track the button clicks globally
var btnClicks = 0;

// create a function the append the form to the DOM on page load.
window.onload = createForm;

function createForm() {

  // initialize out form container
  var f = formContainer();

  // declare the variables we will use in one place
  var itemName, id, className, target, href, btn, text, h2;

  // create an array that will hold the values we wish to pass to our links
  // in the menu
  var listItem = [itemName, id, className, target, href];

  // Create the labels so each input can have a unique label
  var labels = ['Name', 'ID', 'Class', 'Target', 'Link'];

  // Helper text
  h2 = document.createElement('h2');
  text = 'Fill in the fields below to create a new menu item';
  h2.innerText = text;
  f.appendChild(h2);

  // loop through the list items
  listItem.forEach(function(element, index){
    // for each element, call the createDOMNode function and pass in required data
    element = createDOMNode(labels[index], 'input', 'text', 'input_' + index);
    // append each element to the form container
    f.appendChild(element);
  });

  // create the button and give it an onclick handler
  btn = document.createElement('button');
  btn.innerText = 'Create Menu Item';
  f.appendChild(btn);
  btn.onclick = getUserInput;
}

// get what the user inputted into the fields
function getUserInput() {
  // initialize some variables and an array
  var itemName, id, className, target, href;
  item = [];

  // access the values from the input fields
  values = [
    itemName = document.getElementById('input_0').value,
    id = document.getElementById('input_1').value,
    className = document.getElementById('input_2').value,
    target = document.getElementById('input_3').value,
    href = document.getElementById('input_4').value,
  ];

  // loop through each value
  values.forEach(function(element, index){
    // and push it into the item[] array
    if(element !== '') {
      item.push(element);
    }
  });

  // make sure required items are filled out
  if(values[0] === '' && values[4] === '') {
    alert('Name and Link are both required');
  } else if(values[0] === '') {
    alert('Name is required');
  } else if(values[4] === '') {
    alert('Link is required');
  }

  // if the array is not empty, then create the menu
  if(item.length !== 0) {
    createMenu(item);
  }

  // increase the button counter
  btnClicks += 1;

}

// function to create a new menu
function createMenu(item) {
  // create elements needed for menu
  var nav = document.createElement('nav');
  var ul = document.createElement('ul');
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  var f = document.getElementById('formContainer');

  // trying to create the nav only on the first click
  if(btnClicks < 1) {
    nav.setAttribute('class', 'nav');
    document.body.insertBefore(nav, f);
    nav.appendChild(ul);
  }

  var arrayLength = item.length;
  // loop through items and set their attributes
  for(var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    li.appendChild(a);
    a.innerText = item[0];
    a.setAttribute('id', item[1]);
    a.setAttribute('class', item[2]);
    a.setAttribute('target', item[3]);
    a.setAttribute('href', item[4]);

  }
  // and append them to the ul
  ul.appendChild(li);
}

function formContainer() {

  // create the element and set where it is displayed in the DOM
  var formContainer = document.createElement('div');
  formContainer.setAttribute('id', 'formContainer');
  var scriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  document.body.insertBefore(formContainer, scriptTag);

  // style the element
  formContainer.style.width = '360px';
  formContainer.style.margin = '0 auto';
  formContainer.style.border = '1px solid #ddd';
  formContainer.style.padding = '15px';

  return formContainer;

}


function createDOMNode(label, element, type, id) {

  var l = document.createElement('label');
  l.innerText = label;

  // create the node and set it's type attribute
  var node = document.createElement(element);
  node.setAttribute('type', type);
  node.setAttribute('id', id);

  // style the node
  node.style.padding = '8px 4px';
  node.style.width = '100%';
  node.style.marginBottom = '10px';
  node.style.boxSizing = 'border-box';

  l.appendChild(node);

  return l;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new `<nav>` and `<ul>` every time you click the button and appending the new `<li>` item to it.  You only add the first `<nav>` created to the document so all others are being created and never added.  Move your variables for creating your `<nav>` and `<ul>` outside `function createMenu(item)`

```html
<script>  
// track the button clicks globally
var btnClicks = 0;

// create a function the append the form to the DOM on page load.
window.onload = createForm;

function createForm() {

  // initialize out form container
  var f = formContainer();

  // declare the variables we will use in one place
  var itemName, id, className, target, href, btn, text, h2;

  // create an array that will hold the values we wish to pass to our links
  // in the menu
  var listItem = [itemName, id, className, target, href];

  // Create the labels so each input can have a unique label
  var labels = ['Name', 'ID', 'Class', 'Target', 'Link'];

  // Helper text
  h2 = document.createElement('h2');
  text = 'Fill in the fields below to create a new menu item';
  h2.innerText = text;
  f.appendChild(h2);

  // loop through the list items
  listItem.forEach(function(element, index){
    // for each element, call the createDOMNode function and pass in required data
    element = createDOMNode(labels[index], 'input', 'text', 'input_' + index);
    // append each element to the form container
    f.appendChild(element);
  });

  // create the button and give it an onclick handler
  btn = document.createElement('button');
  btn.innerText = 'Create Menu Item';
  f.appendChild(btn);
  btn.onclick = getUserInput;
}

// get what the user inputted into the fields
function getUserInput() {
  // initialize some variables and an array
  var itemName, id, className, target, href;
  item = [];

  // access the values from the input fields
  values = [
    itemName = document.getElementById('input_0').value,
    id = document.getElementById('input_1').value,
    className = document.getElementById('input_2').value,
    target = document.getElementById('input_3').value,
    href = document.getElementById('input_4').value,
  ];

  // loop through each value
  values.forEach(function(element, index){
    // and push it into the item[] array
    if(element !== '') {
      item.push(element);
    }
  });

  // make sure required items are filled out
  if(values[0] === '' && values[4] === '') {
    alert('Name and Link are both required');
  } else if(values[0] === '') {
    alert('Name is required');
  } else if(values[4] === '') {
    alert('Link is required');
  }

  // if the array is not empty, then create the menu
  if(item.length !== 0) {
    createMenu(item);
  }

  // increase the button counter
  btnClicks += 1;

}
var nav = document.createElement('nav');
var ul = document.createElement('ul');
// function to create a new menu
function createMenu(item) {
  // create elements needed for menu
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  var f = document.getElementById('formContainer');

  // trying to create the nav only on the first click
  if(btnClicks < 1) {
    nav.setAttribute('class', 'nav');
    document.body.insertBefore(nav, f);
    nav.appendChild(ul);
  }

  var arrayLength = item.length;
  // loop through items and set their attributes
  for(var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    li.appendChild(a);
    a.innerText = item[0];
    a.setAttribute('id', item[1]);
    a.setAttribute('class', item[2]);
    a.setAttribute('target', item[3]);
    a.setAttribute('href', item[4]);

  }
  // and append them to the ul
  ul.appendChild(li);
}

function formContainer() {

  // create the element and set where it is displayed in the DOM
  var formContainer = document.createElement('div');
  formContainer.setAttribute('id', 'formContainer');
  var scriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  // document.body.insertBefore(formContainer, scriptTag);
  document.body.appendChild(formContainer);

  // style the element
  formContainer.style.width = '360px';
  formContainer.style.margin = '0 auto';
  formContainer.style.border = '1px solid #ddd';
  formContainer.style.padding = '15px';

  return formContainer;

}


function createDOMNode(label, element, type, id) {

  var l = document.createElement('label');
  l.innerText = label;

  // create the node and set it's type attribute
  var node = document.createElement(element);
  node.setAttribute('type', type);
  node.setAttribute('id', id);

  // style the node
  node.style.padding = '8px 4px';
  node.style.width = '100%';
  node.style.marginBottom = '10px';
  node.style.boxSizing = 'border-box';

  l.appendChild(node);

  return l;
}

</script>
```

Comment: This is a good answer but I only want the nav element and ul to be added to the dom on click. Does this do that? EDIT: yes! it does